# Морфологический поиск на php с использованием библиотеки phpmorphy

Tags: php

Как правильно сделать?

Расскажите ваш алгоритм.

Например, две таблицы.
content - посты блога, к примеру
search_index - индексная таблица

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Данная библиотека имеет разные режимы работы, которые могут влиять на скорость загрузки и обработки данных. Так как словари весят от 6 до 15мб, то есть возможность частичной подгрузки словарей. Минус библиотеки состоит в том что нельзя подгрузить сразу 2 и более словарей, к примеру что бы проверять словосочетания: игры online. Так же с кодировками, нужно запрашивать слова в той кодировке что и словарь. Все слова должны быть написаны в ВЕРХНЕМ регистре. Для получения информации о словосочетании вам придется разделать его на массив. Все слова так же будут выданы в массиве, даже если было все одно слово, на выходе вы получите многотомный массив. Вот небольшой пример использования кода:
>
> `$keywords = mb_convert_case($row['keywords'], MB_CASE_UPPER, "UTF-8");
> $list_keywords = explode(" ", str_replace("-"," ", $keywords));
> foreach($list_keywords as $word){
>    if(!empty($word) && $word!=''){
>       if(eregi("[a-zA-z]", $word)){
>            $eng[] = $word;
>       }else{$rus[] = $word;}
>    }
> }unset($keywords);`
>
> `$keywords = array();
> if(isset($rus) && !empty($rus)){
>      $morphyRUS = new phpMorphy($dir, 'ru_ru', array('storage' => PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_FILE));
>      array_add($keywords, $morphyRUS->getPseudoRoot($rus));
> }`
>
> `if(isset($eng) && !empty($eng)){
>     $morphyENG = new phpMorphy($dir, 'en_en', array('storage' => PHPMORPHY_STORAGE_FILE));
>     array_add($keywords, $morphyENG->getPseudoRoot($eng));
> }`
>
> Функция array_add в данном случае делает однотомный массив и склеивает русские и английские словоформы. Если слова нет в словаре, то он возвращает пустой массив.